# Limitations of particle in cell method for high desnity plasma

Tags: particle-physics, simulations, plasma-physics

Are there any limitations of particle in cell (PIC) method for high density plasma? To be more specific, is modelling of a narrow channel of high density plasma possible or are there any limitations connected with PIC approximation?

Comment: You are limited in the number of particles due to memory (RAM), so first limitation I could think of would be that  your channel might be smaller than necessary for some dynamical effects to take place (e.g. instabilities). Not 100% convinced though.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Let's suppose for a while that my memory is unlimited (or the computation is distributed across many computers) therefore my domain can be arbitrarily big.

Comment: IMO, you can't just Willy-Nilly ignore a vital aspect to computing; you've gone from science to science fiction in that case. A colleague of mine was doing a PIC on ~2k nodes (so ~10k props) and had 'only' ~1bn particles & was getting daily calls from the cluster to move his save states from the work to storage nodes. Memory matters.

Comment: Of course, memory matters. I know. However, my intent with the question is not to explore resource limitations but principle limitations. My domain can be also quite small (or periodic) but with lots of particles in it so that density you compute on nodes is very high. Particles can only interact with each other through the grid (if we ignore binary collisions) - this is the PIC approximation. And my question is: Are there any limitations with dense plasmas? I think I'm still at the field of science...but thanks for comment, resource limitation is very important.

Comment: Probably depends on the actual density (e.g. approaching nuclear densities vs typical tenuous space) and *what* you're interested in.

Comment: Ok, from what I know, PIC method is standard technique in low-temperature plasma (glow discharge as an example). But is this method also appropriate for modelling something like lightning, fast streamer, high density pulsed beam of plasma, star?

Comment: I know it to be used in modelling gamma ray burst (GRB) jets which travel at relativistic speeds & have densities probably $n\sim1\,{\rm cm}^{-1}$ (not really sure, but sounds reasonable).

Comment: It is also used to simulated laser-plasma experiments, even at solid-density plasmas. Density is a parameter to account for, but also number of particles per cell, and grid resolution compared to the plasma frequency, or other scales of the problem.

Comment: PIC is also used for shock simulations, magnetic reconnection, and even global magnetospheric simulations for parameters that are consistent with those observed in the near-Earth plasmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complex and broad question.

There are first some technical difficulties:

- The memory consumption, as noted by others.
- The time it takes to compute.

They can be very high, because a very large number of particles may be required to limit the statistical noise. This noise can create many problems, such as numerical plasma waves, strong numerical heating, etc. These limitations can vary drastically from one specific problem to another. It is difficult to assess without knowing your situation.

Secondly, there are physical difficulties:

- Collisions, which can be treated but only with approximations that can fail.
- Collisionnal ionization, which can prove difficult when dealing with exponentially growing number of electrons.
- Field ionization (same problem)
- Recombination and other atomic processes
- Radiation due to these atomic processes or due to Bremsstrahlung, and all the physics related to this radiation interacting with ions or electrons
- Nuclear reactions
- Quantum processes (pair creation, quantum Bremsstrahlung, etc.)
- ... (an endless list really)

You have to define clearly your problem and identify which of these physical aspects require additionnal computation.

Comment: You're right that my question is too broad. I'll think of aspects that you mentioned and soon come with another more detailed question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main limitation on PiC is not density per se, but rather that the plasma should be collisionless. The frequency of collisions is (as a rough approximation)

$\nu \propto \omega_p \cdot \frac{\ln(\Lambda)}{\Lambda} $

where $\Lambda$ is the number of particles in a Debye sphere $\propto T^{3/2} / n^{1/2}$

So what you want a plasma that has low enough density and more importantly that is warm enough that a negligable number of collision happens for the duration of whatever other process you want to study in the first place. Collisions can be added to PiC via MonteCarlo methods, but then things quickly get tricky.

The number of particles and the limit of RAM are less important than you could assume from the comments to your question as you usually don't treat every single electron individually, but group particles of one species that have similar velocities into a single macro particles, reducing the number of computational particle by $10^5 \dots 10^{15}$. The $10^7 \dots 10^{10}$ macro particles that you can hold in RAM can thus cover a large, high density domain.

Comment: You're right that PIC scheme underestimate forces between particles within one cell but as you wrote, these effects can be added using MC methods. It's tricky, be can be done. If you add these effects, is there still a limitation? To the number of particles: it is not that easy - you can use bigger clusters (or superparticles) but you still need to have many (hundreds) particles for a node in order to reduce noise.

Comment: Collisions can be added with different models, which might or might not capture all effects that affect the physical outcome. Furthermore in a strongly collisional plasma kinetic effects are usually not very important and a fluid description would be more appropriate and computationally much cheaper.     Regarding the number of particles: there are of course still limits and you do indeed need a sufficient number of particles per cell, but that is usually not the limiting factor.